# How to export Flutter Project as ZIP in VSCode?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Is there any possibility`(any plugin)` to export Flutter Project as ZIP in VSCode like Android Studio. I am using VSCode for Flutter development and I have to move to android studio for exporting Flutter project to ZIP.

Comment: This is kind of a bad idea, You can just zip your entire source file and extract it some were. But it might give some errors. It is better to just  push it into git and  cloning it(if it is in a different device). If it is in  the same device just copying won't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

Use **git**! Learn about **github** or **gitlab** or **bitbucket**. You can create there free private repositories and .gitignore will help you to ignore useless files from copy.

However, if you really need zip file. Just create script file, for example .bat/.ps1 on windows. Tell me what is your system I will try to help you.

Additionally, You can check vs code extensions marketplace. For example:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-archiver

Comment: Thanks, but its not about learning git as I am a freelancer and I don't want to create an online repo for each project.. and I am using Ubuntu, it would be great if you help me to create a script as you mentioned.

Comment: Did you try to use archiver extension?

Answer (score 0):

If you know what you would like to keep from your existing project (folders / subfolders / files) - here's a shell script that I wrote (should work with `dash`, `bash`, `zsh` shells):

You can save the script as whatever you like, and launch it without parameters (I named it `zenity-select.sh`):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# zenity-select.sh

# A zenity-based .sh script (dash, bash, zsh - compatible) for
# manually marking files and folders in a source directory (recursive) 
# and copying them to another directory (destination)


GET_ROOT_FOLDER () {
    eval $1=\'$(zenity --file-selection --directory .)\'
}

GET_FILES_FOLDERS_OR_TEMPLATE () {
    eval $1=\'$(zenity --list --column Selection --column "Files/Folders" TRUE "Files or Folders" FALSE "TEMPLATE" --radiolist)\'
}

GET_FILES_OR_FOLDERS () {
    eval $1=\'$(zenity --list --column Selection --column "Files/Folders" TRUE "Files" FALSE "Folders" --radiolist)\'
}

GET_FILES () {
    eval ROOT_FOLDER="\"\$$1\""
    eval $2=\'$(zenity --file-selection --multiple --filename "${ROOT_FOLDER}/" --separator "/////")\'
}

GET_FOLDERS () {
    eval ROOT_FOLDER="\"\$$1\""
    eval $2=\'$(zenity --file-selection --multiple --directory --filename "${ROOT_FOLDER}/" --separator "/////")\'
}

GET_DESTINATION_FOLDER () {
    eval $1=\'$(zenity --file-selection --directory .)\'
}

ProcGenerateMarkedArray () {
    
    #Proceed to comparing files:
    
    for i in $(seq 1 $count2); do
        eval markings_$i="0"
    done
    
    for i in $(seq 1 $count2); do
        eval current_file_i="\"\$file_or_folder_to_copy2_$i\""
        eval current_marking_i="\"\$markings_$i\""
        if [ "$current_marking_i" = "0" ]; then
            for j in $(seq 1 $count2); do
                eval current_marking_j="\"\$markings_$j\""
                if [ ! "$i" = "$j" -a "$current_marking_j" = "0" ]; then
                    eval current_file_j="\"\$file_or_folder_to_copy2_$j\""
                    if [ ! "${current_file_i#$current_file_j"/"}" = "$current_file_i" ]; then
                        eval markings_$i="1"
                        break
                    elif [ ! "${current_file_j#$current_file_i"/"}" = "$current_file_j" ]; then
                        eval markings_$j="1"
                    fi
                
                fi
            done
        fi
    done
    
    #Rebuild files array:
    
    count3=0
    for i in $(seq 1 $count2); do
        eval current_marking="\"\$markings_$i\""
        if [ "$current_marking" = "0" ]; then
            count3=$((count3 + 1))
            eval file_or_folder_to_copy3_$count3="\"\$file_or_folder_to_copy2_$i\""
        fi
    done
}

ProcExtractFoldersFromPath () {
    
    eval file_path="\"\$$1\""
    file_path=${file_path#"/"}
    
    first_path_component="${file_path%%"/"*}"
    remaining_file_path="${file_path#*"/"}"
    
    folders_count=0
    while [ ! "$first_path_component" = "$remaining_file_path" ]; do
        folders_count=$((folders_count + 1))
        eval $2_$folders_count="\"\$first_path_component\""
        
        first_path_component="${remaining_file_path%%"/"*}"
        remaining_file_path="${remaining_file_path#*"/"}"
    done
    #Treat last path component separately
    folders_count=$((folders_count + 1))
    eval $2_$folders_count="\"\$first_path_component\""
    
    eval $3=$folders_count

}

trap1 () {
    CleanUp
    printf "\nAborted.\n"
}

CleanUp () {
    
    #Restore "INTERRUPT" (CTRL-C) and "TERMINAL STOP" (CTRL-Z) signals:
    trap - INT
    trap - TSTP
    
    #Restore initial IFS:
    #IFS=$old_IFS
    unset IFS
    
    #Restore initial directory:
    cd "$initial_dir"
}



    TEMPLATE_FILE_DIR_PATH='.'
    TEMPLATE_FILE_NAME='Template_zenity_select.txt'

    cd "$TEMPLATE_FILE_DIR_PATH"
    TEMPLATE_FILE_DIR_PATH="$PWD"
    #If default template file is in $HOME folder, then set its DIRECTORY PATH as: $HOME folder PATH:
    if [ ! "${TEMPLATE_FILE_DIR_PATH#$HOME}" = "$TEMPLATE_FILE_DIR_PATH" ]; then
        TEMPLATE_FILE_DIR_PATH="$HOME"
    fi
    TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH="$TEMPLATE_FILE_DIR_PATH/$TEMPLATE_FILE_NAME"

initial_dir="$PWD"
old_IFS="$IFS" #Store initial IFS value
IFS="
"

#Trap "INTERRUPT" (CTRL-C) and "TERMINAL STOP" (CTRL-Z) signals:
trap 'trap1' INT
trap 'trap1' TSTP


main_count="1"

error1="false"
error2="false"
error3="false"
{ zenity --help >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; } || { error1="true"; }
{ uniq --help >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; } || { error2="true"; }
{ cp --help >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; } || { error3="true"; }
{ find --help >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; } || { error4="true"; }
if [ "$error1" = "true" -o "$error2" = "true" -o "$error3" = "true" ]; then
    {
        printf "\n"
        if [ "$error1" = "true" ]; then printf '%s\n' "ERROR: Could not run \"zenity\" (necessary in order for this script to function correctly)!"; fi
        if [ "$error2" = "true" ]; then printf '%s\n' "ERROR: Could not run \"uniq\" (necessary in order for this script to function correctly)"; fi
        if [ "$error3" = "true" ]; then printf '%s\n' "ERROR: Could not run \"cp\" (necessary in order for this script to function correctly)"; fi
        if [ "$error4" = "true" ]; then printf '%s\n' "ERROR: Could not run \"find\" (necessary in order for this script to function correctly)"; fi
        printf "\n"
    }>/dev/stderr
    CleanUp; exit 1
fi

while [ ! "$main_count" = "2" ]; do
    GET_FILES_FOLDERS_OR_TEMPLATE files_folders_or_template
    if [ -z "$files_folders_or_template" ]; then CleanUp; exit 1; fi
    
    if [ "$files_folders_or_template" = "Files or Folders" ]; then
        SELECT_ROOT_FOLDER="$(zenity --list --column Selection --column "SELECT ROOT FOLDER" TRUE "Select ROOT folder" --radiolist)"
        if [ -z "$SELECT_ROOT_FOLDER" ]; then continue; fi
        GET_ROOT_FOLDER ROOT_FOLDER
        if [ -z "$ROOT_FOLDER" ]; then continue; fi
        
        if [ -z "$files_or_folders" ]; then
            GET_FILES_OR_FOLDERS files_or_folders
            if [ -z "$files_or_folders" ]; then exit; fi
        else
            GET_FILES_OR_FOLDERS files_or_folders
            if [ -z "$files_or_folders" ]; then continue; fi
        fi
        
        files_folders_selection="temp"
        current_file_or_folder="temp"
        count=0
        error="false"
        while [ -n "$files_or_folders" -a -n "$files_folders_selection" ]; do
            if [ "$files_or_folders" = "Files" ]; then
                GET_FILES ROOT_FOLDER files_folders_selection
            elif [ "$files_or_folders" = "Folders" ]; then
                GET_FOLDERS ROOT_FOLDER files_folders_selection
            fi
            
            while [ ! "$current_file_or_folder" = "$files_folders_selection" ]; do
                current_file_or_folder="${files_folders_selection%%"/////"*}"
                files_folders_selection="${files_folders_selection#*"/////"}"
                current_file_or_folder_relative_path="${current_file_or_folder#$ROOT_FOLDER"/"}"
                if [ "$current_file_or_folder_relative_path" = "$current_file_or_folder" ]; then #If "$current_file_or_folder" does not start with "$ROOT_FOLDER":
                    error="true"
                    break
                else
                    count=$((count+1))
                    eval file_or_folder_to_copy1_$count=\"\$current_file_or_folder_relative_path\"
                fi
            done
            if [ "$error" = "true" ]; then
                zenity --warning --width=400 --height=200 --text "ERROR: Last selection parent folder is not \"$ROOT_FOLDER\"! Please try again:"
            fi
            
            if [ -n "$files_folders_selection" ]; then
                GET_FILES_OR_FOLDERS files_or_folders
                if [ "$error" = "true" -a -z "$files_or_folders" ]; then CleanUp; exit 1; fi
            fi
        done
        count2=0
        for line in $(\
            for i in $(seq 1 $count); do\
                eval current_file_or_folder="\"\$file_or_folder_to_copy1_$i\""
                printf '%s\n' "$current_file_or_folder";\
            done|uniq -u;\
        ); do
            count2=$((count2+1))
            #printf '%s\n' "$line"
            eval file_or_folder_to_copy2_$count2=\"\$line\"
        done
        
        ProcGenerateMarkedArray
        
        answer=""
        zenity --question --text "Save this selection to template file?" --no-wrap --ok-label "Yes" --cancel-label "No"
        error_code="$?"; if [ "$error_code" = "0" ]; then answer="Yes"; fi
        
        if [ "$answer" = "Yes" ]; then
            answer=""
            answer="$(zenity --list --column Selection --column "" TRUE "Use default template file path defined in the script" FALSE "Define a template file path" --radiolist --width 480 --height 180)"
            if [ "$answer" = "Define a template file path" ]; then
                zenity --info --width=400 --height=200 --text "Please provide the directory where you want to save the template file:"
                TEMPLATE_FILE_DIR_PATH="$(zenity --file-selection --directory ".")"
                if [ -z "$TEMPLATE_FILE_DIR_PATH" ]; then CleanUp; exit 1; fi
                
                TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH="$TEMPLATE_FILE_DIR_PATH/$TEMPLATE_FILE_NAME"
                answer=""
                if [ -n "$TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH" ]; then
                    zenity --question --text "Are you sure you want to continue? If Yes:\n\nWARNING: $TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH will be overwritten!" --no-wrap --ok-label "Yes" --cancel-label "No"
                    error_code="$?"; if [ "$error_code" = "0" ]; then answer="Yes"; fi
                fi
            elif [ "$answer" = "Use default template file path defined in the script" -o "$answer" = "Yes" ]; then
                
                cat "/dev/null">"$TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH"
                for i in $(seq 1 $count3); do
                    eval current_file_or_folder="\"\$file_or_folder_to_copy3_$i\""
                    printf '%s\n' "$current_file_or_folder">>"$TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH"
                done
            else
                CleanUp; exit 1
            fi
        fi
        
        SELECT_DESTINATION_FOLDER="$(zenity --list --column Selection --column "SELECT DESTINATION FOLDER" TRUE "Select DESTINATION folder" --radiolist --width 400 --height 200)"
        if [ -z "$SELECT_DESTINATION_FOLDER" ]; then CleanUp; exit 1; fi
        GET_DESTINATION_FOLDER DESTINATION_FOLDER
        if [ -z "$DESTINATION_FOLDER" ]; then CleanUp; exit 1; fi
        
    elif [ "$files_folders_or_template" = "TEMPLATE" ]; then
        
        answer=""
        answer="$(zenity --list --column Selection --column "" TRUE "Use the default template file path defined in the script" FALSE "Use a user defined template file path" --radiolist --width 510 --height 180)"
        if [ "$answer" = "Use a user defined template file path" ]; then
            zenity --info --width=400 --height=200 --text "Please provide the template file path:"
            TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH="$(zenity --file-selection --filename ".")"
            if [ -z "$TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH" ]; then continue; fi
        elif [ "$answer" = "Use the default template file path defined in the script" ]; then
            TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH="$TEMPLATE_FILE_DIR_PATH/$TEMPLATE_FILE_NAME"
        else
            continue
        fi
        
        if [ -e "$TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH" -a -f "$TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH" ]; then
            count2=0
            for line in $(cat "$TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH"); do
                count2=$((count2+1))
                eval file_or_folder_to_copy2_$count2=\"\$line\"
            done;
            
            ProcGenerateMarkedArray
            
            SELECT_ROOT_FOLDER="$(zenity --list --column Selection --column "SELECT ROOT FOLDER" TRUE "Select ROOT folder" --radiolist)"
            if [ -z "$SELECT_ROOT_FOLDER" ]; then continue; fi
            GET_ROOT_FOLDER ROOT_FOLDER
            if [ -z "$ROOT_FOLDER" ]; then continue; fi
            
            SELECT_DESTINATION_FOLDER="$(zenity --list --column Selection --column "SELECT DESTINATION FOLDER" TRUE "Select DESTINATION folder" --radiolist --width 400 --height 200)"
            if [ -z "$SELECT_DESTINATION_FOLDER" ]; then CleanUp; exit 1; fi
            GET_DESTINATION_FOLDER DESTINATION_FOLDER
            if [ -z "$DESTINATION_FOLDER" ]; then CleanUp; exit 1; fi
        else
            zenity --warning --width=400 --height=200 --text "ERROR: Default template defined in the script does not exist! Please create one, by not using a template, first."
            continue
        fi
    fi

    if [ -n "$count3" -a ! "$count3" = 0 ]; then
        
        #Proceed to copying files:
        
        error="false"
        count5=0
        
        #Get ROOT_FOLDER_NAME
        ROOT_FOLDER_NAME="${ROOT_FOLDER##*"/"}"
        
        while [ ! -z "$DESTINATION_FOLDER" ]; do
            if [ -e "$DESTINATION_FOLDER/$ROOT_FOLDER_NAME" ]; then
                zenity --warning --width=400 --height=200 --text "ERROR: The destination folder name \"$ROOT_FOLDER_NAME\" already exists in "$DESTINATION_FOLDER"! Please try again:"
                
                SELECT_DESTINATION_FOLDER="$(zenity --list --column Selection --column "SELECT DESTINATION FOLDER" TRUE "Select DESTINATION folder" --radiolist --width 400 --height 200)"
                if [ -z "$SELECT_DESTINATION_FOLDER" ]; then CleanUp; exit 1; fi
                GET_DESTINATION_FOLDER DESTINATION_FOLDER
                if [ -z "$DESTINATION_FOLDER" ]; then CleanUp; exit 1; fi
            else
                cd "$DESTINATION_FOLDER"
                { mkdir "$ROOT_FOLDER_NAME" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; }||{
                    zenity --warning --width=400 --height=200 --text "ERROR: Cannot make root dir: \"$ROOT_FOLDER_NAME\" into destination folder: \"$DESTINATION_FOLDER\"!"
                    CleanUp; exit 1
                }
                #cd "$ROOT_FOLDER_NAME"
                
                for i in $(seq 1 $count3); do
                    eval current_file_or_folder_to_copy="\"\$file_or_folder_to_copy3_$i\""
                    if [ ! -e "$ROOT_FOLDER/$current_file_or_folder_to_copy" ]; then
                        error="true"
                        current_error="ERROR: File \"$current_file_or_folder_to_copy\" does not exist in root (source) folder \"$ROOT_FOLDER\"!"
                        count5=$((count5 + 1))
                        eval error_files_$count5=\"\$current_error\"
                    fi
                done
                
                {
                for i in $(seq 1 $count3); do
                    cd "$DESTINATION_FOLDER/$ROOT_FOLDER_NAME"
                    eval current_file_or_folder_to_copy="\"\$file_or_folder_to_copy3_$i\""
                    ProcExtractFoldersFromPath current_file_or_folder_to_copy folders_array count4
                    for j in $(seq 1 $((count4 - 1))); do
                        eval current_dir="\"\$folders_array_$j\""
                        { mkdir "$current_dir" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; }&&{
                            cd "$current_dir"
                        }||{
                            error="true"
                            current_error="ERROR: Cannot make dir: \"$current_dir\"!"
                            count5=$((count5 + 1))
                            eval error_files_$count5=\"\$current_error\"
                            break
                        }
                    done
                    
                    {
                        cp -r "$ROOT_FOLDER/$current_file_or_folder_to_copy" "." 2>/dev/null
                    }||{
                        error="true"
                        current_error="ERROR: Cannot copy: \"$current_file_or_folder_to_copy\" from \"$ROOT_FOLDER/\" to \"$DESTINATION_FOLDER/\"!"
                        count5=$((count5 + 1))
                        eval error_files_$count5=\"\$current_error\"
                    }
                done
                
                #Remove hidden folders and files (that start with "."):
                cd "$DESTINATION_FOLDER/$ROOT_FOLDER_NAME" && {
                    for i in $(seq 1 $count3); do
                        eval current_file_or_folder_to_copy="\"\$file_or_folder_to_copy3_$i\""
                        if [ -d "$current_file_or_folder_to_copy" ]; then
                            find "." -type d -a -path "*/.*" -a -not -path "." -exec rm -r "{}" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null \;
                        else
                            find "." -not -type d -a -path "*/.*" -a -not -path "." -exec rm -r "{}" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null \;
                        fi
                    done
                }
                
                printf "Done\n"
                }|zenity --progress --pulsate --auto-close --width=400 --height=200 --title="Copying files... " --text="Please wait..."
                
                if [ "$error" = "false" ]; then
                    zenity --info --width=400 --height=200 --text "Files were successfully copied."
                elif [ "$error" = "true" ]; then
                    zenity --warning --width=400 --height=200 --text "ERROR: Errors were encountered while trying to copy files!\nPlease see the next errors list:"
                    errors_list=""
                    zenity --list --width 1000 --height 500 --column "Errors" $(printf $(for i in $(seq 1 $count5); do eval printf '%s' "\"\$error_files_$i\" "; done))
                fi
                
                break
            fi
        done
    fi
    main_count=$((main_count+1))
done

#Restore previous settings:
CleanUp
```